# Smooth scrollIntoView animation stop abruptly when scroll bar fades out on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm using the following code to scroll smoothly to a target element on a page when a button is pressed:

```js
element.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
})
```

This works fine, but sometimes the scrolling stops abruptly before reaching the target element. I identified that the issue happens in the following scenario:

- Chrome Desktop is in a state where the scroll bar is only displayed while scrolling and smoothly fades away shortly after scrolling stops.
- You press the button when the scroll bar is visible, so right after scrolling manually.

The automatic `scrollIntoView` seems to stop exactly at the same time as the Chrome scroll bar fades away and disappears. If you first wait for the scroll bar to fade away and then press the button, `scrollIntoView` works fine.

Same issue happens in Chrome Mobile if you press the button while there's still some "scroll inertia" from previous manual scrolling that's causing the page to scroll. Pressing the button while the page content is moving, causes scrolling to stop immediately but `scrollIntoView` does not take effect.

Might there be some workaround for this, other than to force the scroll bar to display all the time?